# How to start a function as a different process in node.js?

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, fork, child-process

I need to run a function in a node.js application in another process and pass some arguments to that function.
The function definition is in file test1.ts, and I need to call it from test.ts file.

I tried using fork function from `child_process` library, but I don't know how to pass arguments to the function.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.